# How can I position a table at a particular x and y coordinate via reportlab

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, reportlab, platypus

I have the following code which produces a pdf:

```
def colr(x, y, z):
    return (x/255, y/255, z/255)
import reportlab
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, TableStyle, Paragraph, Image, Spacer, Frame, Paragraph
from reportlab.platypus.tables import Table
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleN = styles["BodyText"]
styleN.alignment = TA_LEFT
width, height = A4
logo = '/home/joel/myappointments/appointments/static/clinic/img/logo/logo.png'
elements = []
print(f'Height={height}')
imgw = imgh = 100
im = Image(logo, width=imgw, height=imgh)
im.hAlign = 'LEFT'
elements.append(im)

headstyle = ParagraphStyle(
    name='MyHeader',
    fontName='Helvetica-Bold',
    fontSize=16,
    leading =10
)
doctorstyle = ParagraphStyle(
    name='MyDoctorHeader',
    fontName='Helvetica',
    fontSize=13,
    leading =10
)
data = [[Paragraph("Dr John Doe's ENT Clinic", style = headstyle)], [Paragraph("Dr John Doe", style = doctorstyle)], [Paragraph("ENT Specialist", style = doctorstyle)], [Paragraph("Registration No. ", style = doctorstyle)]]
elements.append(Table(data, repeatRows=1))
line1 = ("Name", "Test", "Age", "20yr")
line2 = ("MRD No.", "18","Date", "14-11-2018")
line3 = ("No.","#", "Doctor", "Dr.John Doe")
data=[line1,line2, line3]
patientdetailstable = Table(data)
patientdetailstable.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (4, 0), '#CFEAD4'),
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 2), (4, 2), '#CFEAD4'),
    ('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1), 0.5, '#CFEAD4'),
    ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1), 0.5, colr(12, 43, 8)),
]))
elements.append(patientdetailstable)
elements.append(Spacer(1, 20))
# We use paragraph style because we need to wrap text. We cant directly wrap cells otherwise
line1 = ["Sl.", "Medicine" , "Dose", "Freq", "Durn", "Note"]
drug1 = Paragraph('AUGMED Syrup 30ml (AMOXICILLIN 200MG + CLAVULANATE(CLAVULANIC ACID) 28.5MG)', styleN)
line2 = ["1", drug1, "1 Tab", "1-0-1", "5 days", ""]
line3 = ["2", drug1, "1 Tab", "1-0-1", "5 days", ""]
data=[line1,line2, line3]
for i in range(3,50):
    temp = [str(i), "Some Drug here", "5 ml", "1-0-1", "10 days", "No comments"]
    data.append(temp)

medstable = Table(data, repeatRows=1)
medstable.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1), 'TOP'),
    ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(-1,0),colors.white),
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colr(40, 196, 15)),
    ('GRID',(0,1),(-1,-1), 0.5, '#CFEAD4'),
                            ]))
elements.append(medstable)
doc = SimpleDocTemplate('output.pdf', pagesize=A4, rightMargin=20, leftMargin=20, \
    topMargin=20, bottomMargin=20, allowSplitting=1,\
    title="Prescription", author="MyOPIP.com")
doc.build(elements)
```

It's all fine, except for the fact that I need the section with: `John Doe's ENT clinic` upto `Registration No` to the right of the logo, instead of underneath it. If I were working on Canvas directly instead of a flowable SimpleDocTemplate, I could easily set its position.

Using a SimpleDocTemplate, how can I position the section arbitrarily?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

I found one solution, which may not be the most elegant of solutions. After fiddling with frames and other flowables, I reread the documentation and found that I could just encapsulate my table within another table just for formatting. Hence I created a one row, two column table and inserted the image in one column and the other table in the second.

```
col1 = Table([[im]])
col2 = Table(data, repeatRows=1)
tblrow1 = Table([[col1, col2]], colWidths=None)
tblrow1.setStyle(
    TableStyle([
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP'),
    ]))
elements.append(tblrow1)
```

Comment: Gosh, how I wish ReportLab had just a bit more documentation and their `platypus` vs regular `canvas` wasn't so different. Anyway, thanks, this helped!